# Quelle est la signification du symbole ¤ ?

Tags: orthographe

Mon clavier AZERTY a un symbole dont je ne connais pas la signification: `¤`.

Quand est-ce qu'il est utilisé?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Au fil du temps se sont dégagés des symboles monétaires permettant de rappeler en quelle devise étaient établis les prix sans avoir à réécrire en toutes lettres le nom de celle-ci.

> Au xxe siècle, les plus répandus étaient la livre sterling (£) et le peso/dollar ($). Le yen (¥) les rejoignit dans les années 1960. L’euro (€) se joignit au groupe de tête en 1999. Un signe fut alors prévu pour désigner un symbole monétaire **générique** lorsque le symbole national n’existe pas dans le jeu de caractères, le symbole : ¤.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbole_mon%C3%A9taire

Ce symbole partait d'une bonne intention mais il faut bien reconnaître que son taux d'utilisation pour cet usage et dans la vraie vie est exactement égal à zéro. Il ne correspond pas à un besoin réel.  (merci @jlliagre !)

Comment: Merci! Je vais faire à l'occasion un quiz au bureau pour voir combien de gens en ont entendu parler :)

Comment: Ce symbole partait d'une bonne intention mais il faut bien reconnaître que son taux d'utilisation pour cet usage et dans la vraie vie est exactement égal à zéro. Il ne correspond pas à un besoin réel.

Comment: À la fois, dans quelle circonstance peut-on indiquer un prix avec sa devise sans avoir besoin d'indiquer de quelle devise il s'agit?